# Create a Map with SimpleEntry and StreamEx

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, streamex

I saw an example of StreamEx wich is quite nice and which goes like this

```
    Map<String, String> toMap = StreamEx.of(splittedTimeUnit1)
            .pairMap((s1, s2) -> s1.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") ? new String[]{s2, s1} : null)
            .nonNull()
            .toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]);
```

This works well an my output is `{seconds=1, minutes=1}` which is ok. Not perfect cause I have to convert the number later on.

I tried to optimize with `SimpleEntry<String,Integer>`:

```
    Map<String, String> toMap2 = StreamEx.of(splittedTimeUnit1)
            .pairMap((s1, s2) -> s1.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") ? new SimpleEntry<>(s1,s2) : null)
            .nonNull()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

which compiles but now I have the problem, that some values are put multiple times into the map which leads to an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key minutes`

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

Stupid Mistake: I forgot to switch s1 and s2 at the second example

```
Map<String, String> toMap2 = StreamEx.of(splittedTimeUnit1)
                    .pairMap((s1, s2) -> s1.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") ? new SimpleEntry<>(s2,s1) : null)
                    .nonNull()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: You are not doing any string to number conversion. You have just swapped key and value—why?

Comment: Yeah, I think that was the problem with the second one. If I switch them everything works as expected, thank you. I want to have the unit as key and the number as value so this is intentional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement seems to be correct, I think the problem was, that I forgot to switch s1 and s2. If I switch them everything works as expected, thank you.